# Jackson deserialize with multilevel inheritance

Tags: java, json, inheritance, jackson, deserialization

I have following situation:

```
public class A {
@JsonDeserialize(using = BaseClassDeserializer.class)
    private List<BaseClass> components = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class BaseClass { }

public class B extends BaseClass { }

public class C extends B { }
```

And deserializer:

```
public class BaseClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<BaseClass>> {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public List<BaseClass> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        List<BaseClass> components = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        ArrayNode componentNode = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        Iterator<JsonNode> elements = componentNode.elements();
        while (elements.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode elementNode = elements.next();
            String type = elementNode.get("typeName").asText();
            BaseClass baseClass = mapper.readValue(elementNode.toString(), resolveClass(type));

            components.add(baseClass);

        }

        return components;
    }
}
```

The `resolveClass` method in current situation returns class `C`. My problem is that I receive Exception  `JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "..."` and this field comes from class B. Current solution would work if I didn't have `public class C extends B { }` but `public class C extends BaseClass { }`, but I have class `B` in hierarchy. Does Jackson support multilevel deserialization somehow?

Comment: Could you provide an example of json to be parsed and exact fields in classes BaseClass,B,C to reproduce the problem?